# pn junction: band bending vs. fermi level bending

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, boundary-conditions, solar-cells

**①**
I have two semiconductors of the exact same material. Hence, the conduction band and the valence band are exactly on the same level. The same holds for the vacuum level.
Now the left one is p-doped, the right one is n doped. Therefore, the (Quasi-)Fermi level in the p-doped material is near `E_v` and the one of n-doped material is near `E_c`, meaning that an electron in the n-doped material has higher potential energy than in the p-doped part.
**First question: Is this even correct, if one plots absolute energy on the y-axis?**

**②**
In semiconductor physics, a pn junction is formed, by shifting the p and n parts in a way that the (Quasi-)Fermi levels are on the same level and one can draw a straight line for the whole device from left to right, which means that an electron has the same potential energy throughout the entire device. If I now compare the height of the (Quasi-)Fermi level, it is higher than in the single p-doped material.
**Second question: Is it true that the energy of an electron deep inside p has now higher energy than before touching n?**
However, the bending is not only performed on the bands but also on the vacuum level. With this one ensures that deep in p it still takes the same amount the extract an electron into free space.
**Third question: Does it even make sense to bend a vacuum level? Shouldn't it be on the same level everywhere in the whole universe?**

**③**
Probably a picture you haven't seen anywhere, but which I often think of. Here I don't chance any vacuum level and I don't bend the bands since I always thought that doping does not change the band structure, but only the filling of the bands, which is exactly what you see on this picture.
**Fourth question: Is this way of thinking wrong and if yes, why?**

[image: pn Junction]